# In Visual Studio Team Services, is there a way to force the board view to recognize existing tests?

Tags: azure-devops

In Visual Studio online, I have a big list of requirements on the board. All of them have Test Cases attached as linked items via a Tested By link. However, they're not showing up.

Both these items have a test attached, by the same link, but only one is recognized by VSO - illustrated by the potion icon.

[image]

I got the top one to pull through to the board by clicking on the ellipsis and choosing "add test" and then putting in a nonsense title. At this point the existing test appears with the requirement/bug and I can remove the nonsense one.

This is cumbersome and time-consuming. Is there another way to get VSO to recognize the attached tests for a test plan?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a test suite for that requirement. On the "Test" hub, you can add a requirement-based test suite for your work item. Any work items added to the test suite automatically appear on the backlog board.

What you're inadvertently doing when you add the "dummy" test is creating a requirement-based test suite.